# Can goblins pull levers?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I am building a fortress that I may eventually want to revisit in adventure mode. If I abandon with my fortress sealed up against a siege, I would like to be able to enter my sealed fortress as an adventurer.

I was planning on putting a drawbridge opening lever on the outside of my fortress to allow me to enter, but then I had the horrible thought: what if goblins can use levers?

If I put a lever on the outside of my fortress to open my front door, am I opening up myself for more fun than normal during a siege?

[This question has been asked for Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/can-mobs-use-levers), but not Dwarf Fortress.

Comment: While I cannot say with authority, I believe that only gremlins and your own people will pull levers. (or any other creature modded to have the MISCHEVIOUS tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goblins cannot pull levers, so you don't have to worry about levers on the outside of your fort. The only creatures who will pull levers in DF fortress mode are are dwarves with the lever pulling labor enabled and gremlins, since gremlins have the MISCHIEVOUS tag.

If you want some extra !!FUN!! when playing in DF fortress mode you can mod the goblins raw files so they also have the MISCHIEVOUS tag, which will then allow them to (randomly) pull levers they find.